# How can i find original transaction id for flutter in app purchase

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I am using  [in-app purchase package](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) to manage subscriptions, but in iOS I cannot check the subscription state from the app. So, I am using the App Store Server API, but I cannot find the purchase `originaltransactionid`. How can I find it?

Comment: Did you found the Solution?